# Add Zero data - Recursive Loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, recursion, dataframe

Background:
I have a data frame that is made up of count data, the numbers of insect nymphs counted from a digital image "Barcode". 
There should be two numbers/counts "NymphCounts" for each barcode one number for each of the two levels of "State" alive 'a' and dead 'd'.

Problem:
The "zero" count data was not always entered for either the state = dead or alive.I would like to add in the missing zero data. 
How can I check each barcode occurs twice and if a barcode number occurs once only duplicate the barcode (observation) and all other variables except add a zero "Nymph count" but make sure the "State" variable is the opposite to the State recorded in the original observation.

Ordinarily, I can find most solutions from other posts. While a number of posts get close I can't seem to solve the following.

Sample data:

```
dput(sampleData)
structure(list(Barcode = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("10308", 
"10309", "10310", "10326", "10327", "10328", "10329", "10330", 
"10331", "10332", "10335"), class = "factor"), Trip = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Source = 
structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L
), .Label = c("P8030265.JPG", "P8030266.JPG", "P8040342.JPG", 
"P8040343.JPG", "P8040344.JPG", "P8040345.JPG", "P8040346.JPG", 
"P8040347.JPG", "P8040348.JPG", "P8040349.JPG", "P8040359.JPG"
), class = "factor"), NymphCounts = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 
16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L), ND.T = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "N/A", 
class = "factor"), 
ND.Z = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "N/A", class = "factor"), 
ND.M = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "N/A", class = "factor"), 
Phone = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("M ", "T"), class = "factor"), 
State = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = 
c("Barcode", 
"Trip", "Source", "NymphCounts", "ND.T", "ND.Z", "ND.M", "Phone", 
"State"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Looked for similar problems and with some help I tried this

```
sampled<-sampleData
str(sampled)
for(i in levels(sampled[,1])){
  if (sum(sampled[,1]==i)==1){
temp <-sampled[which(sampled[,1]==i),]
if(temp$State=="a") temp$State="d"
if(temp$State=="d") temp$State="a"
temp$NymphCounts=0
sampled <- rbind(sampled,temp)
  }
}

write.csv(sampled,"R:/Leo/CWF DATA/sampledcor.csv")
sampledcor<-read.csv("R:/Leo/CWF DATA/sampledcor.csv", header = TRUE, sep = 
",")
```

The result is almost as I would like but not quite ........
BEFORE

```
    sampleData 
    Barcode     Trip  Source         NymphCounts ND.T ND.Z ND.M Phone State
    1    10308    1 P8030265.JPG           1  N/A  N/A  N/A     T     a
    2    10308    1 P8030265.JPG           1  N/A  N/A  N/A     T     d
    3    10309    1 P8030266.JPG           1  N/A  N/A  N/A     T     a
    4    10309    1 P8030266.JPG           5  N/A  N/A  N/A     T     d
    5    10310    1 P8040359.JPG           7  N/A  N/A  N/A    M      a
    6    10326    1 P8040342.JPG           2  N/A  N/A  N/A    M      d
    7    10327    1 P8040343.JPG          16  N/A  N/A  N/A    M      a

AFTER 
sampledcor
X      Barcode    Trip  Source    NymphCounts ND.T ND.Z ND.M  Phone State
1    1   10308    1 P8030265.JPG           1  N/A  N/A  N/A     T     a
2    2   10308    1 P8030265.JPG           1  N/A  N/A  N/A     T     d
3    3   10309    1 P8030266.JPG           1  N/A  N/A  N/A     T     a
4    4   10309    1 P8030266.JPG           5  N/A  N/A  N/A     T     d
5    5   10310    1 P8040359.JPG           7  N/A  N/A  N/A    M      a
6    6   10326    1 P8040342.JPG           2  N/A  N/A  N/A    M      d
7    7   10327    1 P8040343.JPG          16  N/A  N/A  N/A    M      a

RESULTS AFTER  If the present state is `d`dead it duplicates the `barcode` adds a `zero` count and adds the missing alternative state `a`   Great! 
6    6   10326    1 P8040342.JPG           2  N/A  N/A  N/A    M      d
18  61   10326    1 P8040342.JPG           0  N/A  N/A  N/A    M      a
```

However, if the present state is `a` alive the code duplicates the barcode adds a `zero` count and but ALSO duplicates the state instead of changing it to `d`   NOT SO GREAT!

```
7    7   10327    1 P8040343.JPG          16  N/A  N/A  N/A    M      a
19  71   10327    1 P8040343.JPG           0  N/A  N/A  N/A    M      a
```

I would appreciate any direction on how to correct the code so the added observation gets a zero count but also the appropriate state. 
I also get an extra column variable 'X' is there any way to control for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the `{}` in above the text box when editing your post to put your data and code in a more readable format. Just select the block and click on that icon.

Comment: You want to change the value in "NymphCounts" to "0" when there's only a single reading of "Narcode" and the State is "d"? I'm not sure if I'm understanding the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the editing tip lmo

Comment: Thanks Juan Bosco I want to check that each barcode (observation) occurs twice. If a barcode only occurs one time I want to duplicate the observation except for the Nymph count  I want to replace this with a zero and make the state opposite to the initial state recorded. So I end up with two observations same barcode one observation with the number of nymphs 'd' dead and the second with the number that are alive 'a' alive. Hope this helps.